# Make another object invisible from Boolean for OBJ ewport

Tags: modifiers, 3d-view

I am beginner and I am trying to understand how blender works. My basic idea was to make hole inside object using Boolean Modifier. I put cube, apply boolean, then I put sphere as boolean object. So nothing happens, but when I clicked on EYE icon of sphere I got perfect result. Now I try to export this as .obj (which is my goal) and sphere is visible inside windows 3D object viewer. My goal is to only have cube with hole inside. What am I doing wrong?

[image: All objects visible]

[image: Making sphere invisible (I clicked on eye icon)]

[image: Windows 3D viewer]

Answer (score 1):

You haven't selected Selection only when you export .obj-file.

Select your object. Select File -> Export -> Wavefront (.obj).
Check Selection Only checkbox and press Export OBJ

[image: Export .obj]

To fix the topology you need to make sure that there are no overlapping edges.
You can see your object wireframe by checking Wireframe checkbox under Object Properties panel from Viewport Display. You should check this to your object (The Cube).

From same panel change Display As to Bounds for your cutter (The Sphere). This way you can see if there are overlapping edges. Raise or lover the sphere so the edges are as far from each other as possible.

[image: Cutter]

[image: Topology]

And also .obj export is not very good with quads so you need to make all your faces into triangles. Select your object and in Edit Mode press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all. Select Face and Triangulate Faces.

[image: Triangels]

Comment: That works, but windows 3D viewer shows some bugs https://justpaste.it/1oc5v

Comment: There might be something wrong with your topology. You could try changing the sphere z location by a tiny bit so there are no overlapping edges.

Comment: I sitll got same problem, here I showed in video
https://youtu.be/PwWms-QI8Mc
https://youtu.be/slQ4PDCU3ew

Comment: @Nejc Filipič You didn't triangulate the faces. At the end of the video you can see that your topology is still all quads. Look at the last picture I sent. Triangulate faces on Edit Mode.

Comment: That works now after I Applied modifier and triangled the faces. Does that mean I have to triangle faces each time that I apply modifier or only for Boolean method?

Comment: Only triangulate the object you want to export as obj. You only have to do it once.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the "eye icon", all you're doing is hiding the object in the 3D viewport. If you want the object to export correctly, you must first apply the modifier, then (optionally) delete the bool "cutter" object.

[image: BoolCut]